# Camping between Puerto Montt and Santiago in Chile?

Tags: camping, chile

In a couple of weeks we leave for a 3-weeks trip to Chile. For the first 10 days we'll stay in Punta Arenas and in the Torres del Paine national park. Then, we fly to Puerto Montt and have about 7 days to get to Valparaiso.

In these 7 days, we'd like to visit Puerto Varas, Pucon, Chillan, and Talca, although this is only a rough plan. We bring our tent to Chile, along with cooking utilities and so on, so we're well prepared for camping. However, I seem to be unable to find good information about camping sites in the smaller cities on the way between Puerto Montt and Santiago. We are especially asking ourselves, whether it is possible to camp in the national parks around Pucon, e.g., in the Villarrica or Huerquehue national parks.

Where can I find information about that?

Comment: Mind that the Villarica volcano is active. It had a small eruption in march 3rd, so it should be a problem to camp near it. You can find updated info in the chilean geologic and mining ministry at: http://www.sernageomin.cl/volcan.php?iId=22

Comment: removed bit about recommendations for camp sites (subjective, as per our [help]) but asking about where you can find this information is a valid question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and editing the question. I know that the volcano is active, although I am unsure about how this influences the surrounding area. I appreciate your link for up-to-date information about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked in the Chilean Ministry of Tourism site and they have a [touristic services search](http://www.sernatur.cl/buscador-de-servicios) where you can search for campings in specific regions os cities.

Besides that I search the Google and found some others like [campingchile](http://www.campingchile.cl/) which seems a good source, even though I can't be sure of how accurate it is.

Mind that Chile is a country with many volcanoes and they may affect your camping plans. Be sure to check [Chilean Geologic and Mining Ministry](http://www.sernageomin.cl/) for updates on volcanoes activities.